# ASP.Net Identity with IdentityServer fails to get User in controller context

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I followed the documentation [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore2/quickstarts/8_aspnet_identity.html) and was able to get my controllers working with the `[Authorize]` header. I am using IdentityServer with ASP.NET Identity as my user store.

In my `ConfigureServices` I have:

```
services.AddIdentity<KipUser, IdentityRole>()
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<KipDbContext>()
     .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

In my `Configure` I have:

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And in my controller I have done a few tests:

```
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<MyDTO> GetData(int count = 3) {
     var test = User; // The User.Identity.Name is empty for some reason
     var id = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value; // Successfully gets the Guid
     var test2 = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User); // result is null
     var test3 = _userManager.GetUserId(User); //returns null
     var test4 = _userManager.FindByIdAsync(id); // Successfully gets the User from the DB
```

It seems there is a misconfiguration because the UserManager fails to get the ASP.Net Identity from the `ClaimsPrincipal User` variable. Am I assuming too much that the `.AddEntityFrameworkStores<KipDbContext>()` would configure the application to know how to `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User)` instead of me needing to search for the claim myself with this `_userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason I asked this question is because I saw lots of information about this for IdentityServer 2 and 3 that seemed related. I couldn't get those fixes to work in my IdentityServer 4 project so I thought it was a different issue. It is the same issue. As @Tore pointed out, it's an issue with the claims, but I assumed that this would be taken care of with `app.UseIdentityServer();`

[This](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1043) describes the issue clearly:

> UseIdentity and UserManager disagree on where the user ID claim is stored

Even though we are calling `app.UseIdentityServer();` it seems there are some default mappings put in by Microsoft that need to be cleared out.

Per that issue, adding `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();` in the `Startup.cs` `Configure` function before `app.UseIdentityServer();` fixed the problem for me. I can now see the claims are unchanged in the controller, and both `_userManager.GetUserAsync(User);` and `_userManager.GetUserId(User);` work as expected.

Surprisingly, this function call is not included in the `IdentityServerAspNetIdentity` sample project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add this to your client. It fixes the mapping between what Microsoft consider to be the name and what Identity Server consider to be the name claim.

```
options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
};
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: You are right that it has to do with the validation claim configuration. I have seen this documented multiplpe times but I couldn't get it to work but I found that it's my mistake.